# Can't connect Docker + PostgreSQL 9.3

Tags: macos, postgresql, docker, dockerfile

Can anyone help me on this? I'm using Mac OS X El Capitan + Docker.

Dockerfile for my image:

https://gist.github.com/andrealmar/bce56f7d8450990333703aa5c4ac8d61

I run my container:

```
docker run andrealmar/postgresql:9.3
```

*docker ps* shows that my container is running and I do a *docker inspect* to see which IP address the container has:

```
docker inspect 8e65f4dec821 | grep IPAddress
```

Output:

```
"SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
```

When I try to connect using psql:

```
psql -h 172.17.0.2 -U docker docker
```

It gives me a timeout error.

```
psql: could not connect to server: Operation timed out
    Is the server running on host "172.17.0.2" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I've tried also with the command:

```
psql -h 172.17.0.2 -p 5432 -d docker -U docker -W
```

But the same Timeout error happens....

Does anyone knows what I'm missing here?

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to connect to the "internal" (container-container) network of the container. When running on OS X, the docker daemon (and containers) are running in a Virtual Machine.

If you want to access the PostgreSQL database from your OS X machine, you need to "publish" the container's port, to make them publicly accessible. For example, running:

```
docker run -d -p 2345:5432 andrealmar/postgresql:9.3
```

Publishes port 5432 of the container on port 2345 on the host (the virtual machine
in your case).

To access, use the IP-address of the virtual machine, which you can obtain via
docker-machine (assuming your virtual machine is called `default`);

```
docker-machine ip default
192.168.99.100
```

Then connect;

```
psql -h 192.68.99.100 -p 2345 -U docker docker
```

Comment: thank you very much @thaJeztah
you solved my problem.